# WifiP2PManager.creategroup() returning error code 0

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have a problem with mi WifiP2P sharing aplication, it works perfectly on android 5.0,5.1 lollipop or lower but in android 6.0 marshmallow no, first I think that it was a problem with new runtime permissions so I added it to my app but it still not working I always get an error code 0 from the `creategroup()` method but in Lollipop works fine in the same Smartphone

The code:
this is from the button that starts the creation of the server

```
public void StartStream(View view){
    WifiP2PAudioManager manager = new WifiP2PAudioManager(this,WifiP2PAudioManager.SERVER_MODE,DataManager.Uritofile(mMusicPlaybackService.getCurrentSongURI(),this));
}
```

now the constructor of the WifiP2Paudiomanager

```
public WifiP2PAudioManager(SongsActivity activity, int MODE, File AUDIO_SOURCE) {
    this.ACTIVITY = activity;
    this.W_MANAGER = (WifiP2pManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    this.W_CHANNEL = W_MANAGER.initialize(activity.getApplicationContext(), activity.getMainLooper(), null);
    this.MODE = MODE;
    this.AUDIO_SOURCE = AUDIO_SOURCE;
    if (MODE == CLIENT_MODE) {
        this.StartAsClient();
    }
    if (MODE == SERVER_MODE) {
        this.StartAsServer();
    }
}
```

then because we are starting a server here is the method that initialize the peer as a server

```
private void StartAsServer() {
    W_MANAGER.createGroup(W_CHANNEL, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            try {
                SessionBuilder session = new SessionBuilder(AUDIO_SOURCE);
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Created Session");
                Thread Session = new Thread(session);
                Session.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(APP_TAG, "Session error" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Log.d(APP_TAG, "Can't create group error code: " + reason);
        }
    });
}
```

in the create group method is where I have the error it always returns 0 but works perfectly in android lollipop

I hope somebody can help me
thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you provide the logcat output from the device, either with no filter or filtered for "p2p", please.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping but the problem is not in the app, i like to change my ROM and the developer of that maybe do something wrong with Wifi Drivers, i test the app in another Marshmallow Phones and it works perfectly the problem it only with de ROM thanks :)

Comment: Yes, the problem is indeed not in the code, but without the logcat from the device, it is impossible to determine the error at the system level.